# Difference output running Rscript vs source

Tags: r, encoding, rscript

I have the following script:

```
city <- c("Екатеринбург", NA, "Курск", "Псков",
          "березники", "Челябинск", NA, "москва",
          "москва", "Петергоф/Санкт-Петербург",
          "Петергоф/Санкт-Петербург", "Волгоград",
          "Олегегорск", "СПб", "Москва", "Москва",
          "Москва ", "Санкт-Петербург")
city[grep("^(москва|мск|msk)", city, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "Москва"
city[grep("питер|спб|spb|петербург", city, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "Санкт-Петербург"
city[grep("Москва|Санкт-Петербург", city, invert = TRUE)] <- "Другие города"
print(city)
```

When I run `Rscript test.R` I get some results:

```
% Rscript test.R
[1] "Другие города"   "Другие города"   "Другие города"   "Другие города"
[5] "Другие города"   "Другие города"   "Другие города"   "Москва"
[9] "Москва"          "Санкт-Петербург" "Санкт-Петербург" "Другие города"
[13] "Другие города"   "Санкт-Петербург" "Москва"          "Москва"
[17] "Москва"          "Санкт-Петербург"
```

When I run `source("test.R")` I get the different results:

```
% Rscript -e 'source("test.R")'
[1] "Другие города"            "Другие города"           
[3] "Другие города"            "Другие города"           
[5] "Другие города"            "Другие города"           
[7] "Другие города"            "Москва"                  
[9] "Москва"                   "Петергоф/Санкт-Петербург"
[11] "Петергоф/Санкт-Петербург" "Другие города"           
[13] "Другие города"            "Другие города"
[15] "Москва"                   "Москва"
[17] "Москва "                  "Санкт-Петербург"
```

I got correct results when:

- run script with `Rscript`: `Rscript test.R`
- type comands in the R session row by row

With `source()` I got incorrect results (with `Rscript -e` or inside R session).

System info may be helpful:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Arch Linux

locale:
    [1] LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=C              
[5] LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=ru_RU.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] tools_3.2.1
```

Comment: what do you get when you type `Rscript --version`

Comment: `R scripting front-end version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)`.

Comment: run Rscript without -e ; just type `Rscript test.R`...are results the same?

Comment: With `Rscript test.R` all works fine (see output in the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with file encoding. Add the following options to `source`: `encoding="UTF-8", verbose=T`

If you leave off the encoding option (keeping verbose=T option), you will see at the top of the output that the default encoding is `encoding = "native.enc"` which is not what you want for Greek characters.

Comment: Many thanks. `Rscript -e 'source("test.R", encoding="UTF-8")'` works as expected.